# Can anyone recommened some up to date documentation on SEO

Tags: search, google, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I havnt done this for a while and know that search engines are more clever now.

Does anyone know of some good tips or websites to tell me how to do SEO properly, preferably using modern standards (not the old- add 300 tags to the page).

Answer (score 0):

The SEO basics hasn't changed much in years. This [SEO guide](http://www.websitepublisher.net/seo-guide/) covers them well. The only really new stuff worth paying attention to is [microformats](http://schema.org/).